# how to fix / workaround wonky emacs auto-indenting of some C++

Tags: indentation, c++

See the below.  I have two definitions of a floating point array.  The latter is valid with C++11.

The first one is auto indented in a sane fashion.  The second one looks like emacs just doesn't know what to do with it.

I don't really care that much what the auto-indenter decides to do as long as it doesn't look irrational.

Is there a way to fix this or workaround it?

Here is the C++ code, formatted as by the emacs `indent-region` function:

```
int main() {

  // looks good to me
  float nums[9] =
    {
      1., 2., 3.,
      4., 5., 6.,
      7., 8., 9.,
    };

  // wtf
  float * numsp = new float[9]
  {
    1., 2., 3.,
      4., 5., 6.,
      7., 8., 9.,
      };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this with `c++-mode`, but not with `c-mode`. Consider filing a bug report to fix it for C++ mode: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

There's also a related, more-general [thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-10/msg01516.html) about fixing such indentation of data, in `emacs-devel@gnu.org`.